# When creating object I get only last index

Tags: java, selenium, object

What I need is to get search results of users (each user as an object having name, lastNAme, title etc) and then create list of them and do some actions on them.
I am having an issue with returning an object and list of this object with its name. I always get the last record, even though it is iterating through all of them, i.e.

(Object page)

```
public User (WebElement elem) {
List<WebElement> titles = elem.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='userResults']//div[@class='title']"));
        for (WebElement title: titles) {
            setTitle(title.getText());
            System.out.println(title.getText()); // everytime during iteration I am getting different title, which is good
        }
System.out.println(titles.get(0).getText()); // ...but then I get the last index in the search result
}
```

setTitle is a setter

```
public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
```

then I create `List<User>` and I am getting list of the same title. What might be wrong?

Comment: What’s “setTitle”? I mean, if you want a collection, setting a single value won’t really help.

Comment: @DaveNewton 
`public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }`
it's a setter

Comment: so how to create this constructor where I need certain locator for title (for all titles it is the same locator, as above) ? I need to have a `User` object and his properties.

Comment: It’s not clear what you want or mean. If you want a list, make a list. Right now you iterate and keep overwriting “this.title”—is that isn’t what you want, change it, like by saving the title to a list of titles. I can’t determine if that’s what you want.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have a list of users (some search results) and I need to access second, or third one. And I need access to their names etc. E.g. I want to go to second user and assert that his name is John Watson

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the whole context but maybe you need to change the selector. 
You said that you are iterating over specific users. Maybe for each user you should find his specific nested element with title/name or whatever and set it. I imagine i could look like:

```
public User (WebElement elem) {
WebElement title = elem.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='title']")); // find nested element for specific user
           setTitle(title.getText());
WebElement name = elem.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='name']"));
           setName(name.getText());
// and so on...
}
```

Or maybe:

```
public List<User> (WebElement elem) {
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
User user = new User();

List<WebElements> allElements = elem.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='userResults']")); 

for (WebElement single: allElements ) {
            WebElement title = single.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='title']")); 
                user.setTitle(title.getText());
            WebElement name = single.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='name']"));
               user.setName(name.getText());
            users.add(user);
        }

return users;
}
```

Comment: I changed it. But now I have only 1st indx returned Below returns proper values, each title is specific for its indx. Works good:
 `public List<WebElement> getAllUserCards() { List<WebElement> userCards = new ArrayList<WebElement>(); userCards = driver.findElements(userCard); return userCards; }` 

...but this one returns top result only 

`public List<User> getAllUserCards2() { List<User> userCards = new ArrayList<User>(); for (WebElement user : getAllSsersCards()){ userCards.add(new User(user)); } return userCards; }`